# How to prevent inconsistency of caching data

Tags: sql, database, nosql, memcached, membase

My problem: i have many servers do caching data from key-value database. These caching data is frequently updated, then saved back to db. Consequently, the saved data is not the newest one, and i got data missed with high rate.
In my app, performance is more important, missing data is acceptable with low rate.
What's the name of this problem (keyword) and your solution/strategy for it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At low levels this is called the problem of 'Dirty pages'.
There can be 2 issues, old data or no data in db compared to the data in cache. So depending on how much latency the application can afford, you should set the interval at which cache should be flushed to db.